# How to Toggle between elements in Divi?

Tags: jquery, toggle, divi

I need to know if here's a way to make an element appear and disappear when I click another element. I'm working with Divi, so I can't edit the HTML source. I can add CSS and Java Script f needed. 
 
What I want to achieve is this: 
When I click on my **<h2 class="entry-title">**, the **<div class="post-content">** should appear and disappear on every click.

```
<article id="post-301">
                
    <h2 class="entry-title">Best Practices</h2>
                
      <div class="post-content"><div class="post-content-inner et_pb_blog_show_content">
               <p>The ten central child protection steps through which organizations will progress as part of the Aleinu campaign.</p>
</div></div>            
</article>
```

I tried adding this script, but didn't work at all:

```
<script>
jQuery(function ($) {
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $(".entry-title").on("click", function(){var x = document.getElementsByClassName(".post-content");
            if (x.style.display === "none") {
            x.style.display = "block";
            } else {
            x.style.display = "none";
};
});
});});)
</script>
```